# The Mabinogion sheep problem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, martingales

$\textbf{The Mabinogion sheep problem}$ By David Williams

> There is a magical flock of sheep, some black, some white. We sacrifice poetry for precision in specifying its behaviour. At each of times 1,2,3,… a sheep (chosen randomly from the entire flock, independently of previous events) bleats; if this bleating sheep is white, one black sheep (if any remain) instantly becomes white; if the bleating sheep is black, then one white sheep (if any remain) instantly becomes black. No births or deaths occur.
>
> The controlled system.
>   Suppose now that the system can be controlled in that just after time 0 and just after every magical transition time 1,2,…, any number of white sheep may be removed from the system. (White sheep may be removed on numerous occasions.) The object is to maximize the expected final number of black sheep.
>
> Policy $\bf{A}$ : at each time of decision, do nothing if there are more
>   black sheep than white sheep or if no blakc sheep remain; otherwise,
>   immediately reduce the white population to one less than the black
>   population.
>
> We define the value function $V : Z^{+} × {Z} ^{+} → [0, ∞)$ so that $V (w, b)$ is the expected final number of
>   black sheep under Policy $\bf{A}$ if there are $w$ white sheep and $b$ black sheep at the start. As a result,
>   V has the following properties,
>
> a1) $V(0,b)=b, V(w,0)=0$ .
>   a2) $V(w,b)=V(w-1,b)$ whenever $w\ge b>0$
>   a3) $V(w,b) = \frac{w}{w+b}V(w+1,b-1)+\frac{b}{w+b}V(w-1,b+1)$ whenever $0<w<b$
>
> $\textbf{Question (a)}$ : Show that under the policy $\textbf{A}$, $V(W_n,B_n)$ is a martingale w.r.t. filtration $\mathcal{F}$, where $\{W_n,B_n\}$ is number of white and black sheep after $n_{th}$ time.
>
> $\textbf{Question (b)}$ : Suppose $V(w,b) \ge \frac{w}{w+b}V(w+1,b-1)+\frac{b}{w+b}V(w-1,b+1)$ and $V(w,b) \ge V(w-1,b)$ whenever $w\ge0$ and $b \ge 0$.
>   Show that for any other policies, $V(W_n,B_n)$ is a super-martingale w.r.t. filtration $\mathcal{F}$.

Recently, I am studying martingale and its application. And I am very curious about this question in the textbook. This is a famous stochastic control problem by David Williams, called The Mabinogion sheep problem. The following is described in (Williams, David (1991), Probability with martingales, Cambridge Mathematical Textbooks, Cambridge University Press)

In the David Williams's book, he just mentioned about a1)-a3) three properties but not proved them.

$\textbf{My attempt}$:

$\textbf{The property a1)-a3) are what we have known, they are very easy to show.}$

$\textbf{For my proof to Question (a)}$

$E\{V(W_{n+1},B_{n+1})|\mathcal{F_n}\} = \frac{W_n}{W_n+B_n}V(W_{n}+1,B_{n}-1) + \frac{B_n}{W_n+B_n}V(W_{n}-1,B_{n}+1) =V(W_{n},B_{n})$.
Therefore, $V(W_{n},B_{n})$ is a martingale w.r.t. $\mathcal{F_n}$

$\textbf{For my proof to Question (b)}$

$E\{V(W_{n+1},B_{n+1})|\mathcal{F_n}\} = \frac{W_n}{W_n+B_n}V(W_{n}+1,B_{n}-1) + \frac{B_n}{W_n+B_n}V(W_{n}-1,B_{n}+1)  < V(W_{n},B_{n})$.
Therefore, $V(W_{n},B_{n})$ is a super-martingale w.r.t. $\mathcal{F_n}$

Do I miss some points for proving (a) and (b)? Could you help me to check my answer?

$\textbf{Edit:}$ .

$\textbf{This question has not been answered for Question (a) and (b)}!$ .
$\textbf{Could I get some helps from these two question? Thank you so much!}$

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really anything to prove. The properties of $V$ come from the description of Policy A.

There's also no need to consider an arbitrary $n.$ For this kind of first-step analysis you only need to consider the case $n=0$ and use time-invariance. But I'll use $(W_n,B_n)$ to refer to the number of white and black sheep just after time $n,$ after a sheep has changed color if possible ($n>0$) but before any sheep are removed by the control policy.

a1 - immediate from the definition of $V$ as the expected final number of black sheep, for the obvious cases where all the sheep are black or all are white

a2 - by the Policy A rule "immediately reduce the white population to one less than the black population", a system with $(W_0,B_0)=(w,b)$ with $w\geq b>0$ has the same behavior as the system with $(W_0,B_0)=(w',b),$ for any $w'\geq b-1$

a3 - this is the expected value of $V(W_1,B_1)$ when the control rule "do nothing if there are more black sheep than white sheep" is used, using the distribution of $(W_1,B_1)$ as you state in the rough idea at the end of your question, with $a_n=0$

Comment: Thank you very much! But I am still confused about a2). That means for any $w \ge b >0$, whatever $w$ is, then $V(w,b) = V(w+1,b)$For example, $w=10$, $b=8$ and $w=11$, $b=8$, they will immediately reduce the white population to one less than the black population by Policy $\textbf{A}$. So they have same behavior Am I correct? Thank you. @Dap

Comment: @EmilyElle: Yes, so starting with $b=8,$ if $w$ is eight or greater then $w$ is immediately reduced to $7.$

Comment: Thank you for your reply. for a2) we need to prove $V(w,b) = V(w-1,b)$ whenever $w \ge b > 0$.  So if we start with $w= 8$ and $b= 8$, so there the other behavior is $w^{'} = w-1=7, b = 8$. Since the magic transition is before than control, so if the magic transition pick up a white sheep, then it is transformed to black. So $w=7, b=9$, we can regard it as the start point by time invariance, so it is obviously different from the second behavior $w^{'} =7, b=8$. Did I miss some points? Thank you! @Dap

Comment: @EmilyElle: you get to remove white sheep "just after time 0", before the magical transition. The very first thing that happens is you get to remove sheep to ensure $w<b.$ The timeline I have in mind is: there are sheep $(W_0,B_0),$ then the control occurs, then the transition occurs at time $1,$ then there are sheep $(W_{1},B_{1}),$ and so on.

Comment: Thank a lot. I got it, the control should occur before the first transition. By the way, do you know how to conclude that $\{W^{A}_n,B^{A}_n\}$ (Under Policy $\textbf{A}$) is a martingale w.r.t. filtration ${\mathcal{F}_n}$ where $\{W_{n},B_{n}\}$ are the white and black sheep after $n_{th}$ time. My attempt is $E\{V(W^{A}_{n+1}, B^{A}_{n+1})\big|\mathcal{F}_n\} = \frac{W_n}{W_n+B_n}V(W_n+1,B_n-1)+\frac{B_n}{W_n+B_n}V(W_n-1,B_n+1) = V(W_n,B_n)$. Do you think I miss some steps to check $\{W_{n},B_{n}\}$ is a martingale? @Dap

Comment: @EmilyElle: $V(W_n^A,B_n^A)$ is a Doob martingale. The random set $\{W_n^A,B_n^A\}$ isn't a martingale since it's not a (random) real or vector.

Comment: Thank you! @Dap. But I am a little confused, since in the David Williams's book, he said $V(W^{A}_{n},B^{A}_n)$ is indeed a martingale w.r.t. the filtration $\sigma(\{W_t,B_t\}:t \le n)$. He did not give the proof, so I tried to prove it.

Comment: @EmilyElle: you're best off asking a new question about this if you want more clarification

Comment: Thank you so much! @Dap